# How to find queries that are same in each direction?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am a little rough on my SQL and I am trying to figure out how to get only the entries of the table that are same both on source and destination.

I created a small db here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05afc7/10)

```
SELECT *
FROM Routes
INNER JOIN Cities src
ON (src.ID = Routes.Start)
INNER JOIN Cities dest
ON (dest.ID = Routes.Destination)
WHERE
    [Not sure what to put here]
```

I am trying to find that if you have the route A->B and B->A, it will return those entries. So my query should return (1,3) and (3,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with doing a self-join, but your join condition had a problem.  You want to retain routes with the following properties:

- The *end* of the first route is the *start* of the second route
- The *start* of the first route is the *end* of the second route

In the query below, I select only the starts of each matching route, since the ends will be duplicates of some other start.

```
SELECT r1.Start,
       c.Name
FROM ROUTES r1
INNER JOIN ROUTES r2
    ON r1.Destination = r2.Start AND
       r1.Start       = r2.Destination
INNER JOIN Cities c
    ON r1.Start = c.ID
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Why not put the `r1.Start = r2.Destination` in the join criteria, too?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT r1.Start,
       c.Name
FROM ROUTES r1
INNER JOIN ROUTES r2
    ON r1.Destination = r2.Start
INNER JOIN Cities c
    ON r1.Start = c.ID

> you just need to put the only "r1.Destination = r2.Start" rest is handled by DB engine